# Function to multiply 2 arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I need to make a function that multiplies 2 arrays and puts the result in a third array that I will print using another "print function".
So If I input array11: 5, 10, 20; and array22: 1, 2; I should get this result:
result_array:5, 10, 10, 20, 20, 40. So each element from the first array is multiplied with each element from the second array and stored in a third array.

But I don't get the expected result. Instead I get some random numbers.
Can you help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

- `array11` and `array22` are the first 2 arrays
- `array_result` is the resulting array
- `dim1` and `dim2` are the dimensions of the first 2 arrays
- `dim3` is the dimension of the third array which is calculated outside the
  function like this:

  ```
  dim3 = dim1 * dim2;
  ```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void remplir(int array[], int dim);
void aficher(int array[], int dim);
void multiplier(int array11[], int array22[], int dim1, int dim2, int dim3);

int main() {
int dim1 = 0, dim2 = 0, dim3;
cout << "La dimension de la 1ere table?" << endl;
cin >> dim1;
while (dim1 > 20) {
    cout << "La dimension maximum est 20! Reessayez!" << endl;
    cin >> dim1;

}
int array1[dim1];
remplir(array1, dim1);
aficher(array1, dim1);

cout << "La dimension de la 2eme table?" << endl;
cin >> dim2;
while (dim2 > 20) {
    cout << "La dimension maximum est 20! Reessayez!" << endl;
    cin >> dim2;

}
int array2[dim2];
remplir(array2, dim2);
aficher(array2, dim2);
cout<<"////////////////////////////////////////////////////////"<<endl;

dim3 = dim1 * dim2;
multiplier(array1, array2, dim1, dim2, dim3);
cout << "dim3 = " << dim3 << endl;
return 0;

}

void remplir(int array[], int dim) {
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < dim; i = i + 1) {
    cout << "Entrez la case numero " << i << endl;
    cin >> array[i];

}
}
void aficher(int array[], int dim) {
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < dim; i = i + 1) {
    cout << "indice " << i << " = " << array[i] << endl;

}
}

void multiplier(int array11[], int array22[], int dim1, int dim2, int dim3) {
int i, j, k = 0;
int resultat[dim3]; //resulting array
for (i = 0; i <= dim1 - 1; i = i + 1) {
    for (j = 0; j <= dim2 - 1; j = j + 1) {
        resultat[k++] = array11[i] * array22[j];
    }
}
aficher(resultat, dim3); //function that prints the resulting array
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`k` never gets incremented, so you keep storing the value of the multiplied arrays in the first element of `array_result`. You could try:

`array_result[k++] = array11[i] * array22[j];`

That will use the value of `k` and then increment it afterwards. You should also consider default-initialising your `array_result` like so:

`int array_result[dim3] = {}; // initialise all values to 0`

That would mean you wouldn't get random numbers and you'd see all numbers but the first were 0.

Comment: Be careful with changing code in your question once an answer is posted. My answer does not reflect the new code in your question. Others should note my answer is based on the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30226865/1)

Comment: The function "multiplier" is still there. I just added the rest of the code.